detecting rotation angle of coin image
What is the best way to determine the angle of an image of a coin?
The image is a fixed resolution (400x400), but may be off-center by a few pixels in any direction.
The image can have different colors, lighting, rotation, etc.


I have tried various CNN ideas without success. It seems that the similarities between rotated images that are otherwise identical is not enough augmentation.
I am unable to find an existing dataset for this purpose
Please give me some pointers to ideas that have been proven to work, not theory

How did you exactly try to train the CNN? I would try to make it detect features that are prominent and also not symmetrical like the head in the given example using segmentation. Based on the orientation of the predicted polygon you can estimate the rotation of the coin.

ML can be a part of this, in several steps, but it's not the only part of the solution. first you need to locate the thing (its center and radius). then you really should determine some canonical orientation for it. then you should extract whatever features you like, but do it in a polar space (i.e. polar warp and work in the cartesian result). then you can run comparisons on clusters of features (histograms or signatures). or screw all the prep work (rotation, warp) and do the clustering on straight up SIFT/AKAZE feature vectors. see also [tag:cbir].

btw: "I want to identify coins" has been asked a suspicious number of times in recent years. you'd do well to do some literature review, or at least search for forum threads and previous questions.

@DaSt I have used other model definitions from various tutorials as I haven't been able to find any good resources to tell me how to identify specific features. This seems to be a void of information on the internet. The segmentation you mention...is it something in ML(tensorflow) of manually extracting sections of all images used for training/testing ?
